# Any idea what's up?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("#uploadMe").change(function(e) {
            var input = $(this);
            var file = input[0].files[0];
            var fileName = file.name;
            var template = '<div class="j_upload_item">' +
                                    '<span class="j_label">Uploading <pre></pre></span>' +
                                    '<div class="j_upload_progress progress progress-striped active">' +
                                        '<div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>';

            box = $("#j_upload_box").append(template);
            box.hide();
            box.fadeIn(200);
            box.find('pre').text(fileName);
            bar = box.find('.bar');

            formData = new FormData($('form')[1]);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/admin/callbacks/upload.php?type=email-attachment',  //server script to process data
                type: 'POST',
                xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandler, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                //Ajax events
                beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
                success: successHandler,
                error: errorHandler,
                // Form data
                data: formData,
                //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            function beforeSendHandler(e) {
                bar.css('width', '0%');
            }
            function successHandler(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                bar.parent('div').addClass('progress-success');
                bar.css('width', '100%').delay(3000).queue(function(next) {
                    box.fadeOut(500);
                    next();
                });
                var curval = $("#j_attachments").val();
                var arr = $.makeArray(curval);
                arr.push(data.name);

                $("#j_attachments").val(arr);
            }
            function errorHandler(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            function progressHandler(e) {
                bar.css('width', ((e.loaded / e.total) + '%'));
            }

        });
```

`$("uploadMe")` is a file input. This script is supposed to upload the file and display a small progress box defined by `template`. Instead of the boxes fading out and going away like they're supposed to, they keep popping up every time the `change` event is fired.

So what happens is I end up with 3 boxes stacked on top of each other with the same stuff inside.

If you need clarification just ask. This is really annoying me :(

Comment: Stupidest title for a question, you might as well have just said "I have a problem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZKS5/)

```
        bar.css('width', '100%').delay(3000).queue(function(next) {
          box.fadeOut(500,function(){
                $(this).empty(); //empty the container.
             });
            next();
            });
```

Issue is that you are adding the `j_upload_item` everytime and not emptying the container and the fadeIn is on the container so it just pops out the appended message which gets accumulated over time during each file upload.

Comment: It works! The only issue now is that only 1 thing can be processed at a time. Have any idea if that could change?

Comment: @sun-tzu Could you elaborate please. `Only one thing can be processed at a time`

Comment: Only one file can be uploaded and processd at one time. When one file is uploding more files cant upload at the same time.

Comment: Also, the same file cannot be uploaded twice without refreshing. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're doing

```
box = $("#j_upload_box").append(template);
```

This will append a new div each time the change event is fired... Perhaps this is your issue?

Comment: That's what I want. But I want the div to fade out and be removed when the upload finishes. I tried using `remove`, but that doesn't allow for more uploads. It's appending the box and then fading in all of the previously appended boxes.

Comment: You seem to be setting the same variable, "box", each time the function is called. Perhaps instead of: box = ... you can try doing var box = ... ?

Comment: Do the same with bar, i.e. initialize both box and bar with var box = .... and var bar = ... - you're referencing bar directly from inside successHandler()